# Ubuntu WSL2 not able to connect to host ip port - Wireguard

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wireguard

I recently updated my OS from Windows 10 to Windows 11 and so switched from WSL1 to WSL2. I have an Ubuntu app running in windows using WSL2.

Now I have setup a tunnel to redis in AWS so that I can access redis using localhost and some port that I have assigned in putty. I cannot connect to AWS only if I am in Wireguard VPN.

I can connect with this setup in Windows machine with VPN the redis service in AWS

However in Ubuntu, I cannot connect to the host and port but not able to connect(was working in Windows 10 with WSL)

I tried to use the ip in /etc/resolv.conf instead of localhost as mentioned in one of the stackoverflow posts and also tried using hostname.local and port and this too did not work.

Has anyone come across such scenario?

Comment: What worked for me, as per comments in [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/7895) was changing MTU to 1400, command is `sudo ip link set eth0 mtu 1400`.

Comment: Alternatively you can downgrade the machine to WSL v1 if that's an option.

Comment: @orhtej2 thank you I downgraded the machine to WSL v1